# Adding html variables dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables

I want to add html variables : "`<script>var var1 = new CalendarPopup();</script>`" according to a number that the user chooses. At the moment I have an ajax setup that is suppose to change my  tag to add the variables by changing the inner html like so :

```
<div id="calVar">
    <script>
        var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();
        var cal2 = new CalendarPopup();
    </script>
</div>



        function addRespDropDownAjax(currentNumberOfDropDown)
    {

        //Prepare a new ajaxRequest.
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        //Ajax receiving the response in this function
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            //state 4 is response ready.
            //Status 200 is page found.
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {


                document.getElementById('calVar').innerHTML = '<script>var cal3 = new CalendarPopup();</script>';
                    alert(document.getElementById('calVar').innerHTML);

            }
        };

        //Send the Ajax request.
        xmlhttp.open('GET','mainServlet?command=ajax.AddRespDropDown&NUMBER_OF_DROP_DOWN=' + currentNumberOfDropDown, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

The last alert :document.getElementById('calVar').innerHTML return nothing and my varaibles are not created. any ideas?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: That is a JavaScript variable, not an HTML variable. Why not just create the JS in the script?

Comment: You're really overthinking this.

Comment: `window.cal3 = new CalendarPopup();`. Done.

Comment: Are you getting the 200 response? Did you try debugging (breakpoints)? Is the addRespDropDownAjax called after the div? Why not assign cal3 directly (as previous commenters noted).

Comment: @Friso I can't debug it really. I am using eclipse and I can't install any other programm because it is not my computer.

Comment: FireBug? Else try firebug-lite. The debugging should (in this case) happen in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't have variables, and any that are defined in a `<script>` without deeper nested scope can be simple defined off the `window` object.

Instead of trying to insert HTML, just use:

```
window.cal3 = new CalendarPopup();
```

then any other script can access this variable now or later.